# Adding 'orWhere' to laravel eloquent model relationship

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have a model relation like the below one in `User` model,

```
public function notifications(){
    return $this->morphMany('App\Notification','receiver')
                ->orWhere('type', 2);
}
```

This works well if there are no other conditions. But if `$user` is an instance of `User` and i call like, `$user->notifications->where('status', 1);`,

query condition becomes,

> select * from `notifications` where `notifications`.`receiver_id` = 3
>   and `notifications`.`receiver_id` is not null and
>   `notifications`.`receiver_type` = User or `type` = 2 and `status` = 1

here the problem is, the final condition is working as an `OR` since i'm not able to group the relation's conditions. Therefore, even if the base relationship condition fails, but just the `status & type` fields match, it will fetch that record.

What i need is to add a parenthesis before the first where and close after the relation conditions, so that any other where condition applied will not affect the base query.

What i need:

> select * from `notifications` where **(**`notifications`.`receiver_id` = 3
>   and `notifications`.`receiver_id` is not null and
>   `notifications`.`receiver_type` = User or `type` = 2 **)** and `status` = 1

Answer (score 1):

Check out [Parameter Grouping](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/queries).

Something like this:

```
Notifications::where('receveier_id', '=', 3)
->whereNotNull('receveier_id')
->where(function ($query) {
       $query->where('receiver_type', '=', 'User')
             ->orWhere('type', '=', 2);
})
->where('status', '=', 1);
```

Comment: Thanks! This works and I'm aware of parameter grouping. My doubt was about including the morphMany in the group and was looking for a solution like @kapil.dev's answer. Unfortunately that didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Try this..

```
public function notifications(){
    return $this->where(function($query){
                       $query->morphMany('App\Notification','receiver')
                             ->orWhere('type', 2);
                 })
}
```

Replace your code with this code in Model

Hope this works

Comment: It didn't! `Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::morphMany() `

Comment: oohh , may be you can manually write all the condition as suggested by SteD in another answer

Comment: Thanks! I did that and it worked. But I was expecting something like this :)